# Not able to place the space in textbox

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.restrict').bind('keyup blur', function (e) {

    var newStringVal = $(this).val().replace(/ /g, "");

    $(this).val(newStringVal.replace(/[^\x00-\x80]+/, ''));




});
```

This is the jquery code to restrict arabic font and allow only english. But space is not working now..

Comment: You are removing them using `.replace(/ /g, "")`, remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing **space** with **empty** in your code. The below line is causing this issue.

```
//var newStringVal = $(this).val().replace(/ /g, "");
```